# Where will the TLB entries be stored if the cache memory get full (or can this situation occur)?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management

As we know that the entries of the TLB get copied into the cache memory once another process is chosen to be run by the scheduler. But what if the cache memory is full and there is no space left for the entries to be copied?

Comment: Do we know this? Usually a process switch doesn't affect the TLB at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your premise appears to be faulty.  As far as I know, normally no such thing happens on a context switch.  Either the TLB is left unchanged; or the TLB has entries "evicted" (removed from the TLB; but not copied somewhere else, they are just deleted from the TLB).

Comment: Tagged TLBs are totally a thing, of course.

Comment: @Pseudonym, yup (I think they fall under the "left unchanged" category) but in any case they don't cause entries to be copied out of the TLB on a context switch.